# How can I get these Haskell data types to align?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a simple REST API in Haskell that uses Scotty. After a lot of work, [my database layer](https://github.com/JonathanReeve/corpus-db/blob/22fd44a2a31a67ab0006ed5ed5afab990ba91fc5/src/db.hs) works, and can retrieve a row from my sqlite database. And [the API end](https://github.com/JonathanReeve/corpus-db/blob/22fd44a2a31a67ab0006ed5ed5afab990ba91fc5/src/Main.hs) works, too, and I can go to localhost/api/etc and it returns JSON like it should. But I can't seem to connect all the parts. Really I don't know how Haskell data types can be converted to each other. When I try to [put the two together, as in this file](https://github.com/JonathanReeve/corpus-db/blob/ca4ba9195576f830cfae1c3bdc3f0e40c0502bde/src/Main.hs), I can't seem to align the types correctly. The error I'm getting is:

```
Main.hs:41:15: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘IO’
                     with ‘Web.Scotty.Internal.Types.ActionT
                             Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text IO’
      Expected type: Web.Scotty.Internal.Types.ActionT
                       Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text IO Connection
        Actual type: IO Connection
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: conn <- connectSqlite3 db
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘do { conn <- connectSqlite3 db;
              meta <- getByID conn "9.0";
              json meta }’
```

How do I convert an `IO` to a `Web.Scotty.Internal.Types.ActionT Data.Text.Internal.Lazy IO Connection`? And also why do I have to do this?

Comment: I will leave "why" to a more philosophical answer.  As for how, you can use [`lift`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#v:lift) which takes actions in a base monad to actions in a transformer.  E.g. `lift (putStrLn "hello")` will have type `ActionT t IO ()`

Comment: Why? Because the types are different. Why are the types different? Because they do different things. A scotty action isn't just an IO action. It's a description of an http request handler that can embed IO actions inside it.

Comment: @luqui, it's probably a better habit to use `liftIO` than to use `lift` directly here.

Comment: @dfeuer Why? For the same reason as it's better to use `map` if you have just`[a]  -- A list` ?

Comment: @Kindaro, because `liftIO` will lift through any transformer stack, while `lift` only lifts one step.

Comment: So what I'm hearing is that the scotty `do` syntax is different from a `main` do syntax in that it needs to be a certain kind of monad? So I have to get things from a base monad to a transformer monad. But how do I import `lift`?

Comment: @Jono, `import Control.Monad.Trans (lift)` (or `liftIO` if you want to take dfeuer's suggestion)

Comment: `do` is a built in concept in the Haskell language and the syntax is the same no matter the monad.